# Linking errors from MATLAB Mex library

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, linker-errors, mex

I am having troubling compiling a MATLAB Mex library - specifically, the 'Correlation Clustering Optimization' code from [this website](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html).

I am trying to compile on an OSX machine, and am using the supplied `mexall` function. This runs the following line:

```
mex -O -largeArrayDims CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -Wno-write-strings" QPBO.cpp QPBO_extra.cpp QPBO_maxflow.cpp QPBO_wrapper_mex.cpp QPBO_postprocessing.cpp -output QPBO_wrapper_mex
```

The error occurs at linking time with the following output to the MATLAB command line:

```
ld: duplicate symbol QPBO<int>::GetMaxEdgeNum()    in QPBO_extra.o and QPBO.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "QPBO_wrapper_mex.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

Judging from this, the function `GetMaxEdgeNum` is appearing in both `QPBO_extra.o` and `QPBO.o`. However, it is only actually defined in a header file, `QPBO.h`. I therefore suspect that both source files which include it are including it as a symbol in their object files, causing a problem at link time.

(Further information: Each source file also includes a file `#include "instances.inc"` at the very *end* of the file. `instances.inc` apparently seems to include some specific instantiations of the templated `QPBO`.)

Is there an obvious mistake I am making here? What can I do to increase my chances of being able to compile this code?

**EDIT**

This is the definition of the problematic `GetMaxEdgeNum` function in `QPBO.h`:

```
template <typename REAL> 
    inline int QPBO<REAL>::GetMaxEdgeNum() 
{
    return (int)(arc_max[0]-arcs[0])/2;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Some more details about my machine:

- OSX 10.6.8
- MATLAB R2012a (also have R2011b)
- g++ 4.2 or g++ 4.0 (or g++ 4.6 via MacPorts)

I've added some details on what I really want from an answer in my 'bounty description' below.

**EDIT 3**

There's a bit of consensus that `instances.inc` may be causing the trouble. This is included at the end of each `cpp` file, and it contains the following:

```
#include "QPBO.h"

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(disable: 4661)
#endif

// Instantiations

template class QPBO<int>;
template class QPBO<float>;
template class QPBO<double>;

template <> 
    inline void QPBO<int>::get_type_information(char*& type_name, char*& type_format)
{
    type_name = "int";
    type_format = "d";
}

template <> 
    inline void QPBO<float>::get_type_information(char*& type_name, char*& type_format)
{
    type_name = "float";
    type_format = "f";
}

template <> 
    inline void QPBO<double>::get_type_information(char*& type_name, char*& type_format)
{
    type_name = "double";
    type_format = "Lf";
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, it's from @[Shai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai)'s website, so you have your own first hand source for support :)

Comment: Yes, I have contacted him directly but he says he has no experience with its compilation on OSX. The part that is failing is really a third party library, so as I say below I think I'd ideally have someone with OSX to hand to help fix this problem...

Comment: It might be helpful if you would paste in the specializations of the QPBO template that are in `instances.inc`.  (Just the prototypes of these functions should be fine, I don't actually need to see their code contents.)

Comment: @BillCheatham - I suspect the problem is related to the `instaces.inc` file. Can you remove it and the `save` method from `qbpo.*` (it is not used for large scale CC).

Comment: Thanks @Shai I gave this a go, but now I'm finding that the linking fails from undefined symbols referenced from QPBO_wrapper: `Undefined symbols:
  "QPBO<int>::Solve()", referenced from:
      void QPBO_wrapper...` etc. I agree that I think `instances.inc` is trouble!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the issue is that some template code is in .cpp files.

1. Remove the `#include instances.inc` declarations from the `.cpp` files.
2. Move all code from **QPBO.cpp**, **QPBO_extra.cpp**, **QPBO_maxflow.cpp** and **QPBO_postprocessing.cpp** to the header file **qpbo.h**.
3. You'll have now a single .cpp file **qpbo_wrapper_mex.cpp** and a single header **qpbo.h**
4. mex the file (in matlab) using:

   ```
   >> mex -O -largeArrayDims qpbo_wrapper_mex.cpp
   ```

Should work...

Comment: Excellent, this works. Thanks for your work... both on the library and in fixing this for me!

Comment: @Shai +1 to you, sir, and a well-deserved bounty. I had no doubt that you'd be able to solve this :)

Answer (score 3):

Changing `GetMaxEdgeNum` to a static function, or putting it in an anonymous namespace will probably fix your problem.

The reason is, as you suggest, that it has external linkage in both object files, which results in a nameclash. My suggested solutions gives it internal linkage.

*After edit:*

Does it change anything if you define the method inside the class definition? 
Like this:

```
template <typename REAL>
class QPB0 {
    ...
public:
    inline int GetMaxEdgeNum() 
    {
        return (int)(arc_max[0]-arcs[0])/2;
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a go (added word `static` before `int` in the function - see edit to question). However, I then got some errors about `cannot declare member function 'int QPBO<REAL>::GetMaxEdgeNum()' to have static linkage`. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: It means that my answer was only valid if your function was not a member function, which I assumed it wasn't. The inline keyword should do the same trick, so I don't know why you get that linker error.

Comment: Thanks, I've given it a go and it definitely should work - it just doesn't. I'm still getting the same linker errors. Not really sure what to do next, but I will try some different includes or compiler options. I think part of the issue is the strange `instances.inc` included at the bottom of each source file...